# Inner join not works

Tags: mysql

After a long work on it i am here going to ask my question, its simple but i don't know why it is not working, please help!!!

I have a table

**phpfox_friend**  (where i have the below columns)

- friend_id
- user_id
- friend_user_id
- ordering

**phpfox_user** (where i have below columns)

- usre_id
- user_name
- status_id
- full_name

I am trying to inner join it by using below mentioned Sql query, but it give me an error

> `#`1054 - Unknown column 'phpfox_friend.user_id' in 'on clause'

**Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM `phpfox_friend` 
INNER JOIN `phpfox_user` 
  ON `phpfox_friend.user_id`=`phpfox_user.user_id` 
WHERE phpfox_user.user_name IS NOT NULL
```

Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong in it

Comment: It looks like phpfox_user has the field usre_id, not user_id. Or is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `phpfox_friend` 
INNER JOIN `phpfox_user` ON 
`phpfox_friend`.`user_id`=`phpfox_user`.`user_id` 
WHERE `phpfox_user`.`user_name` IS NOT NULL
```

you need to add the quotes to tables and to the fields.

so use

```
`phpfox_friend`.`user_id` instead of `phpfox_friend.user_id`
```

Comment: So nice of you...with full of respect